# How to format a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with column named amount. I want to display it in such a way that there are always 10 digits. The amount should be right justified with the last two digits displaying cents. If there are no cents then the last two digits should be 00
for eg:-

```
Name   Amount   New Column
---------------------------
aa      287.66  0000028766
bb       66     0000006600
cc     2475.1   0000247510
dd      214     0000021400
```

Comment: Do you want to actually create a new column or replace the values of the current `Amount` column?  Also what's the data type of `Amount`?

Comment: Why is 214 not ...21400 ?

Comment: Prime use of [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) IMO... provided you want it to update when amount changes.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you're right. My bad.

Comment: Sql version? Column data type?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Format(CAST(Amount * 100 as INT), 'D10')
```

Or

```
Format(Amount * 100 , '0000000000')
```

As long as you are on at least 2012.

Comment: Would you _recommend_ `format()`? [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: @SqlZim unless the OP is returning hundreds of thousands of rows yes. the slightly greater CPU time it may use isn't going to make any practical difference in most scenarios and it is more self documenting. At least to people familiar with the standard format strings.

Answer (score 2):

you can use right function in sql server as below:

```
select name, Amount, NewColumn = right('0000000000'+ convert(varchar(10),convert(int,amount*100)),10) from yourtable
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim for your inputs

Comment: You must convert it to int before: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=68f91993354850f5aef00203b136d947

Comment: Yep... else we will get extra zeros

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REPLICATE()][1] function for this purpose.

Just to avoid decimal point you should convert to integer before to cast is as a varchar.

> ```
> DECLARE @MyVal decimal(18,2) = 1252.23;
> SELECT REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(CAST(CAST(@MyVal * 100 AS INT) as VARCHAR(10)))) 
>        + CAST(CAST(@MyVal * 100 AS INT) as VARCHAR(10))
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 0000125223       |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=635f7b7e0816499f422a8181b7cd1716)*

Answer (score 1):

As long Amount is string and has a blank space.

```
   DECLARE @T TABLE
            (
              NAME VARCHAR(10) ,
              Amount NVARCHAR(254)
            )

        INSERT  INTO @T
                ( NAME, Amount )
        VALUES  ( 'aa', N'     287.66' ),
                ( 'bb', N'      66  ' ),
                ( 'cc', N'    2475.1 ' ),
                ( 'dd', N'     214  ' );
        WITH    CTE
                  AS ( SELECT   name ,
                                amount ,
                                IIF(ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(Amount, ' ', '0')) = 1, CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(REPLACE(Amount,
                                                          '.', ''), ' ',
                                                          '0')), 0) AS NC
                       FROM     @T
                     )
            SELECT  name ,
                    amount ,
                    FORMAT(NC, '0000000000') [New COLUMN]
            FROM    CTE
```

Result

```
    name       amount        [New COLUMN]  
    ---------- -----------   --------------
    aa              287.66   0000028766
    bb               66      0000006600
    cc             2475.1    0000247510
    dd               214     0000021400

    (4 row(s) affected)
```